# Restrict access to folder in external HDD before lending it to someone

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, security, permissions

I have a HDD that I will lend to a friend of mine for a couple of days. There are some folders with personal files that I want to keep them private without temporary deleting them. What's the most efficient method on Windows 8/10?

For now, I've managed to restrict the access to any machine that is not my PC by `right-clicking on a folder > Properties > Advanced... > Encrypt contents to secure data.`

I'm not fully satisfied because I would like to restrict the access to both the files and the folder. Instead, with this method the user can still navigate in it and read the filenames (without opening them, though).

Is there something built-in on Windows? I'd prefer to not use an external tool.

Comment: You can't.  The drive could be formatted.  The drive could be read within Linux.  The permissions could be changed by an Administrator user.  Windows is the only OS that will restrict access to the folder, unless its encrypt, even then it could just be deleted.  So backup your data.  *Even better don't lend out devices, with personal data on it, to other people if you don't want those other people to have access to your data.*  Put the Folder inside a folder then encrypt and restrict access to it.

Comment: I suppose you could use something like a TrueCrypt container or a .VHD, the files inside either container, would need to be encrypted.  But again the actual container file could be copied any number of ways.  Just setting the permission, then allowing access to the file on a machine you don't have control over, cannot prevent a file from being copied.

Comment: So with the method I've tried everyone that is Administrator **even on another PC** can still change that permission? Can you confirm this? Anyway I've tried to copy or deleting it from my notebook and I can't, it asks for a permission and I can't acquire it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Obviously, my friend can format the hard drive and delete everything, but we are overestimating the situation.

Comment: Unless you encrypt the files.  The permissions could be changed using an OS under their complete and total control.  Its just that simple.  Since you have already encrypted the files using EFS, and FDE would require you giving them the password to the drive ( which would give them access to the files on the dirver ), you have done all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is delete the data off the disk.  It will take more time to do anything else than its worth.  Setting up file or disk encryption takes time.  And of course you have to test to see if it works.  That takes even more time.  It takes a fraction of a second to delete the data.  Even if the data is secured, it can be taken and theoretically cracked.  With no data, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Since we are talking about a friend and the personal data are just photos... I actually don't mind the fact that they could be deleted. My only worries are that he can not _view_ them.

Comment: as i said, just delete them.  that takes no time.  encryption is overkill.

Comment: I'm just curious about a non-invasive method instead of cancellation. I know it's the most secure way but, let's face it, I'm just giving it to a friend and the data is not sensible.